# How can I filter an index view using REST?

Tags: 8

I have a custom content type called 'Regions', which simply has a title field. Example values are: Asia, North America, Ocenia, etc.

I've set up a view for this list and a REST export for it, so `/regions` gives me a simple list:

`[{"title":"Asia"},{"title":"North America"},{"title":"South America"},{"title":"Ocenia"}]`

I want to filter the results, so I added a contextual filter on the title field, making `/regions/Asia` show only Asia:

`[{"title":"Asia"}]`

How do I implement a wildcard search? Something like `as` should match `Asia` and `amer` should match both `North America` and `South America`. I'd like to do something like `/regions?title=Asia`

I referred to [this guide on setting up contextual filters](https://medium.com/kevinblanco-io/drupal-views-the-power-of-contextual-filters-bac1be8eddf7), but the following doesn't seem to work for me:

> This query works as a SQL `LIKE` statement so you can send just a piece of the name and Views will try to find all records `LIKE` that argument, example, I have a brand called `Land Rover` but if I just send `Land` as an argument it will work http://dev-cars-api.pantheonsite.io/api/cars/Land

The URL in the quote is no longer online, so I can't check if it actually works. For me, only entering a full, matching item title works. I can't even specify a title with spaces, so `/regions/North+America` is also blank for me.

My Drupal version is 8.4, running on PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a search filter to the view.

In the view settings, under `Filter Criteria`, you'll see `Content: Published (= Yes)` and `Content: Content type (= Regions)` (or whatever your view is for).

1. Click add. In that box that shows all the fields you can add, type `Search: Search Keywords`.
2. Tick `Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it`.
3. (optional) Rename the Filter Identifier from `keys` to `query` or `terms` or whatever you see fit.
4. Save the view.

You'll then be able to make a `GET http://example.com/api/regions/?_format=json&keys=my+search+string`!